# How does Wildcard work with StrField in Solr?

Tags: solr

There are quite a few links that detail the difference between StrField and TextField. Also links that explain that, even though the field is indexed, it is not tokenized and stored as a single keyword, as can be verified by the debug analysis on Solr admin and CURL debugQuery options.

What I am unable to understand is how a wildcard works on StrFields? For example, if the name is "John Doe" and I search for "John*", I get that match. Which means, that somewhere deep within, maybe a Trie or Dictionary representation exists that allows this search with a partial string.

I would have assumed that wildcard would match on TextFields which allow (Edge)NGramFilters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it the wrong way around - using a TextField with a NGramFilter would allow hits *without* using wildcards, as they would generate a large amount of tokens:

```
foo => f, o, o, fo, oo, foo
```

Searching for just `fo` would then match an existing token (or if you're expanding ngrams on query as well, match `f`, `o` and `fo`).

In a wild card search (this might not be the actual implementation today, but it explains how it would work), Lucene can look at all the tokens in the list for the field, starting from the prefix provided (as this is a sorted list), then iterate over the values available until it comes to a value that doesn't share the same prefix. A range query over alphanumerical values would require the same functionality.

This is also why the reverse wild card filter makes sense - it adds a reversed token for each value, allowing you to transform `*foo` to a search for `oof*`.

As any wildcard search eliminates the analysis stage (it's *really* hard to make sense of analysis on a wildcarded string, and it might not do what you'd expect it to do), the end result is to "just" get the range of tokens that matches the prefix.